# how to access complex object in php

Tags: php, object

I have the following data structure $all =

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [abc@gmail.com] => Array
            (
                [usr] => 130
                [fname] => Bob
                [lname] => thekid
                [email] => abc@gmail.com
                [news] => 0
                [wres] => 1
                [SWAGLeaders] => 0
                [cca-cpg] => 1
                [cleanup-cpg] => 0
                [gas-cpg] => 1
                [pollinators-cpg] => 0
                [climate-int] => 0
                [composting-int] => 0
                [energy-int] => 1
                [other-int] => 0
                [pollinators-int] => 0
                [recycling-int] => 0
                [transport-int] => 1
                [trees-int] => 0
                [water-int] => 0
            )

    )
```

How do I access the inner keys/values?

I tried `print_r($all[0]['abc@gmail.com']);` but that produced nothing

also, is 'abc@gmail.com' a key? or a variable?  I thought it was a key whose value is the array and then inside the array we have  additional key/value pairs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is clearly an object (denoted by the `stdClass Object` in that output), not an array. You can access it with `$all->{"abc@gmail.com"}`. This is how you force complex interpolation in place of a PHP symbol, where the symbol violates PHP's naming rules. So for example, object properties with dashes, or other illegal symbols, in them can be forced to be evaluated as strings and then as property names by wrapping them in strings and then in braces: `$obj->{"this-is-ok"}` whereas `$obj->this-is-not`.

As a side note, if this object comes from JSON, you can always force it to be stored as an array by utilizing the second argument of `json_decode()`, which if set to `true` will force the object to be built as an array instead. For some people this may make the dereferencing of keys easier. So if `$all["abc@gmail.com"]` seems more natural to you than `$all->{"abc@gmail.com"}` that might be the better approach.